# send data from my controller to my ngDialog

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my controller i have this code, i get the id from one table in the html template and get one object from services and return to ngDialog to show to Edit this data and save in my api-rest:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app')
        .controller('FraseController', FraseController);

    FraseController.$inject = ['FraseService','ngDialog'];

    function FraseController(FraseService,ngDialog) {
        var vm = this;
        vm.texto   = rpeuba;
        vm.iden    = 0; 
        vm.efrase   = '';

        vm.edit = function(){           
            FraseService.get().then(function(response){
                console.log(response.data.response);
                vm.efrase = response.data.response;
                ngDialog.open({ 
                    template: 'newFrase',
                    scope: this
                });
            });         
        }       
    }
}());
```

and in this html code:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="newFrase">  
      <h1>Nueva Frase {{vm.texto}}</h1>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="frase" class= "col-lg-2 espaciar">Frase: </label>
                <div class="col-lg-10">   
                    <input ng-model="frase.efrase.frace" type="text" name="frase" id="frase" class="form-control" placeholder="Escriba su frace aquí">
                </div>  
                <br>     
                <label for="autor" class= "col-lg-2 control-label espaciar">Autor: </label>        
                <div class="col-lg-10 ">               
                    <input type="text" name="autor" name="autor" class="form-control" placeholder="Escriba el Autor aquí">                      
                </div>  
                <br>
                <label class="col-lg-2 espaciar">Banner: </label>
                <div class="col-lg-10">
                    <select name="banner" class="form-control selectize-input espaciar">
                        <option value="0"><< Ninguno >></option>
                        <option ng-repeat="itemb in FraseController.lbanner" value="{{itemb.id}}">
                            {{itemb.titulo}}
                        </option>              
                    </select>
                </div>        
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" 
                class="btn btn-default" 
                ng-click="closeThisDialog('tiempo')">Cancelar</button>
        <input name="submit" value="Insertar" class="btn btn-primary" title="Insertar" type="submit">        
      </div>  
</script>
```

i want to show data from my controller in my ngDialog to Edit a one Frase

Answer (score 0):

Good morning, here are how to solve all my problems with ngDialog.
as I run for an answer to what I call ngDialog.openConfirm and on the response run my controller methods mother and passed as a parameter an object from which consume your data.
This is my code to delete a frase.
JS in my controller:

```
vm.drop = function(__frase){ //Drop the frase
            ngDialog.openConfirm({
                template:   '<h3>You are sure to delete the phrase<h3> '+                            
                            '<div class="modal-footer"> '+
                                '<button type="button" '+
                                    'ng-click=closeThisDialog("Cancel") '+
                                    'class="btn btn-default">Cancel'+
                                '</button> '+
                                '<button type="button" '+
                                    'ng-click=confirm(dfrase.frase.id) '+
                                    'class="btn btn-primary">Delete</button> '+
                            '</div>',
                plain:true, 
                controllerAs: 'dfrase',               
                controller: [function() {
                    var vm = this;                    
                    vm.frase = __frase;                                      
                    }]                
                })
            .then(
                function(value) { //ok                    
                    FraseService.drop(value).then(function(response) {
                        console.log(response.data.response);
                    });
                    refresh();
                },
                function(value) { //cancel
                    console.log(value);
                }
            );
        }
```

FraseService consumer that is a factor with which it interacted with my api and refresh method refreshes me the frase list items.
D greetings